# ol.overlay is not setting the position correctly

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using openlayer 3.9.0 .I have the below code , in which i have to draw a number of overlay on map.

These overlay are coming but not at exact coordinate. But as soon as i click on map some where these overlay moves to correct position.

To overcome tis i tried to hit click event on hidden div also but it is not working. Only when i click on map somewhere then only these anamoly go tpo correct position.

```
for(var anamolyIndex=0; anamolyIndex< self.anamolyes.array.length ; anamolyIndex++)
            {                       
                tmpAnamolyObject = self.anamolyes.array[anamolyIndex];
                elem = document.getElementById(tmpAnamolyObject.coordinates);
                coordinate = tmpAnamolyObject.coordinates.split(",");
                longitude = parseFloat(coordinate[0]);
                lattitude = parseFloat(coordinate[1]);
                position = ol.proj.transform([longitude, lattitude],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');                  
                popup = new ol.Overlay({
                    //position: position,
                    element: elem,
                    stopEvent:true,
                    positioning : 'center-center'
                });
                tmpAnamolyObject.type = "ANAMOLY";
                popup['identity'] = tmpAnamolyObject;
                elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    var coordinates = this.getAttribute('id');
                    self.send('onAnamolyClick',coordinates);
                });
                popup.setPosition(position);
                self.map.addOverlay(popup);                 

            }
```